# Not able to access iOS SQLite database: sqlite3_prepare_v2 and 'no such table' sqlite3_errmsg

Tags: ios, ios5, sqlite, ios-simulator

This is the first time I'm trying to create and access a SQLite db in iOS and I followed a tutorial, but I can't make this work. These are the steps I've followed:

1. Created a database through the Firefox plugin ("testDatabase") and a
   table ("testTable") with several columns
2. Saved the "testDatabase.sqlite" file in a directory
3. Dragged and dropped such file into my "Supporting Files" group in my
   Xcode project
4. Added "libsqlite3.dylib" in Build Phases > Link Binary With
   Libraries
5. Added "-lsqlite3" in Build Settings > Linking > Other Linker Flags >
   Debug and Release
6. In a ViewController, called this method:

   ```
   -(NSString *)copyDatabaseToDocuments {
       NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
       NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testDatabase.sqlite"];
       if ( ![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath] ) {
       NSString *bundlePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testDatabase.sqlite"];
           [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:filePath error:nil];
       }
       return filePath;
   }
   ```
7. Then, trying to write in the database:

   ```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testDatabase.sqlite"];
   sqlite3 *database;

   if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
       const char *sqlStatement = "insert into testTable (id) VALUES (?)";
       sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

       if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

           sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 1, newObject.ID);
       }

       if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
               sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
       }
   }
   sqlite3_close(database);
   ```

I have read several posts regarding a similar error, but nothing of what I tried has worked for me... I also tried with `NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testDatabase" ofType:@"sqlite"];` but it is null, and also have underplayed and redeployed my app in the simulator several times...

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you build your app, have you verified that the testDatabase.sqlite file is actually part of the app bundle (in the same directory as Info.plist and your other resources?

Comment: Yes, it is located at that directory, and it is also listed in the target's Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this working by simply deleting the app folder generated in  */Users/[user]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/* to be created again when running the simulator